# What is the difference between array and keyed List?

Tags: tcl

Can anyone explain the difference between array and keyed list? In my perspective both are doing same.

can anyone differentiate these? Which is best to use?

Answer (score 7):

Both are conceptually associative maps.

A Tcl array is a compound variable that is a collection of simple variables. Each variable may hold any value (no, variables aren't values) and the array is indexed by arbitrary values. There is *no* defined order of keys. As with any variable, you can set a trace on an array or on any element of an array. You can also `vwait` on them.

A TclX keyed list is a value that holds other values, and it is indexed by values (with some restrictions because `.` is used as a structured index separator). I *think* the key order is “insertion order” but I'm not 100% on that. Keyed list elements have no particular identity.

You can put a keyed list in an array element, but you can't put an array in a keyed list at all.

Which is best to use? It really depends on what you're doing. Arrays are built into Tcl itself; you've always got them. Keyed lists depend on the TclX package being present.

---

There's also dictionary values built into Tcl from 8.5 onwards; they've got a different syntax to keyed lists for reasons that are a little unfortunate. However, they also have a lot more support commands and they support bytecode compilation, making dictionaries rather faster than keyed lists. You've still got arrays though, as arrays aren't values and dictionaries aren't variables.

Comment: A Tcl array is a compound variable that is a collection of simple variables. A TclX keyed list is a value that holds other values,.. I am little bit confused about these statements ? Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: Arrays are faster that "lists" , why then programmers introduced Keyed List ?

Comment: A variable is a *named* thing which holds a value.  In `set x 10`, `set` is the name of a command, `x` is the name of a variable and `10` is a string *value* which will be assigned to the variable named `x` after that command completes.  When we call the next command, `set y $x`, the interpreter will access the variable named `x`, pull *a value* (which is a string `10`) out of it and assign it to another variable, `y`.  So variables are means to store values.

Comment: Now the distinction between Tcl arrays from other Tcl containers (`list`s, `dict`s, TclX's keyed lists) is that the former manipulate *variables* while the rest manipulates *values.*  That is, when you do `set foo(x) 10`, a *variable* is created for the `foo(x)` array entry; at this point it can only be referred to using the array syntax, `foo(x)`, but you can easily create another reference to it: `upvar #0 foo(x) bar` and then do `puts $bar`. That is, `foo(x)` is a true variable and you can do with it everything you can do with a variable in Tcl.

Comment: Contrary to arrays, other containers store mere values: the command `list a b c` creates a list of three strings, `a`, `b` and `c`, and returns the created list as another *value,* so unless you assign it to a variable it's lost.  The same holds for those three strings: they are just values contained in that list value, they are not variables by themselves and you can't access them as variables: to get, say, the 2nd element from the list's value you have to apply a special command: `puts [lindex [list a b c] 1]` would create our list, extract and print its 2nd element, and throw the list away.

Comment: As to why keyed lists... Arrays are not faster -- basically the same machinery (hash maps) are used to access their elements -- they have different *semantics* to keyed lists/dictionaries.  For instance, since arrays refer to variables *they are not values themselves,* and that's why you can't return an array from a procedure *by value* (like you can, say, for a list).

Comment: I'd say, if you have Tcl >= 8.5 (and you *should* these days) and want "hash maps", use `dict`.  Understanding arrays in Tcl require certain getting used to as they are different to what you have in PHP, Python, Perl etc.